# Visual prints garbage letters - Caesar cipher excercise

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, caesar-cipher

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"


int main()
{
    char name[100];
    int key;
    printf("enter plaintext:\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    int length = sizeof(name);
    printf("please enter key:");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("plain text: %s\n", name);
    printf("ciphertext:");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         if (name[i] >= 65 && name[i] <= 90) {
             int c = (int)(name[i] - 'A');
             char d = 'A' + (char)((c + key) % 26);
             printf("%c", d);
        }
         else if (name[i] >= 97 && name[i] <= 122) {
                int c = (int)(name[i] - 'a');
                char d = 'a' + (char)((c + key) % 26);
                printf("%c", d);
        }
        else
           printf("%c", name[i]);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Hello,
So this is an exercise I have been trying to solve in the course "cs50" by Harvard.
It's a ceaser cipher , it takes a string, a key, and prints the encryption:
c=(pi+k) % 26

c - the final decrypted letter
pi = the position the the letter ( a=0. b = 1..)
k = the key

My program gives the right output, but the last row prints garbage chars:
[image]

I though it was because memory allocation? But i haven't touched it yet, and I don't want to use the cs50.h package because I want to learn c the way it is, and not use "strings" variables like they do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have `sizeof` bytes in your buffer but `%s` initializes only as many bytes as it reads. Instead of looping up to `length`, loop only to `strlen(name)` (and include `<string.h>`)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the line

```
int length = sizeof(name);
```

the `sizeof` operator returns the size of a variable in bytes.  In this case, since `name` is a `char[100]` the size of this object is 100 bytes.  In the example you gave the plaintext (and ciphertext) were both much smaller so your loop ran over and started printing garbage memory (i.e. space that you allocated but didn't use to store the message).

What you need to use instead is

```
int length = strlen(name);
```

which returns the length of the string.  Be sure to include the `string.h` header.